# Get form Titlebar color from Delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi, tform

My question is simple, but I can't find any information about it. I need to detect, from Delphi, some information about the TitleBar; for example which is the height and particularly which is its color? I think there is some windows API, but I've found nothing on the web. Can someone suggest me how to reach these tasks.

Comment: Is it your app. Is it themed. Which OS versions do you support.

Comment: Title bars on Windows haven't been a *single* color since Windows 95. Windows 98 introduced gradients, Windows XP introduced highlights around the edges, and Windows Vista introduced a translucent effect. Which of the possibly hundreds of colors on the title bar do you want?

Answer (score 0):

To get the heigth of the tile bar you could use [GetSystemMetrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx) API (with `SM_CYCAPTION` as parameter).

For caption area color - there is some [system colors defined in Graphics unit](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Colors_in_the_VCL), ie `clActiveCaption` and `clInactiveCaption`, these are colors that are defined in the Windows Control panel.

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted, it answers the question.

Comment: I'm not sure it is right if the app is themed though

Comment: My app is under Windows 10 and it's not themed. I know the system colors like clActiveCaption, but it differ from the color that windows give to the caption of the app window. with the API DwmGetColorizationColor i get it, but also in this case it is similar but not the same of the titlebar of the window

Comment: @eros please address the comment that Rob left